# In asm, how does printf() knows how many variables are being passed in?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, printf

In the world of assembler language, when you call `printf()`, you do:

```
push arg_N
push arg_N-1
..
push arg1
push format
call _printf
```

But how does `printf()` here know how many arguments are passed in?

Comment: printf analyzes the format string to know how many arguments and what type to expect.  That's also why mismatched format strings and arguments can cause really bizarre problems.

Comment: it *doesn't* and thats the point for why it can be unsafe if you don't keep your arguments and your format string in-sync. The format string is all they have to go on.

Comment: And note that it isn't even implementable in calling conventions where the callee pops the arguments (e.g. _pascal). Only the caller can know how many arguments there were.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just walks along the string, consuming parameters as it finds %-format items. If there are less arguments than %-items, then something awful happens.